# -moz-max-content does not work for mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, mozilla

How do I fit a div to the contents inside in mozilla firefox?

Making a div fit a content using -moz-max-content does not affect dynamic size, when new elements are added into the div.

I have tried the following:

1. It only acts equally to height: 450px

```css
.login-container{
   height: auto;
   max-height: 450px;
}
```

2. Div gets full height of body

```css
.login-container{
   max-height: fit-content;
   height: -moz-max-content;
}
```

(1) gives the expected result but automatically sets height to max-height.

(2) div is being stretched to the bottom of the page.

Basically, I want a dynamic sized div container based on the elements inside.

Comment: What do you want to ask actually?

Comment: Sorry, I will revise the question after this comment. My question would be, {height: fit-content} works perfectly fine with Google Chrome. But then in mozilla they use {height: -moz-max-content}; I also tried {height: -moz-fit-content}: but then none of these actually works. How do I fit a div to its content for mozilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-moz-*-content` not worked on `height`

how to know it

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
  var text = $( this ).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
  text.replace('&#10;','<br/>'); 
  $('div').html(text);
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:#00ffff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}
div.yourfit{
  background-color:#ff00ff;
  max-width:-moz-max-content;
  max-height:-moz-max-content;
}
div.myfit{
  background-color:#ffff00;
  max-width:-moz-max-content;
  min-height: 50px;
  height:auto;
}

/*Dont care*/
textarea{
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>

<div class="myfit">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
<div class="yourfit">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

For use dynamic height with content... only use this

```
  min-height: 50px;
  height:auto;
```

Comment: max-width:-moz-max-content; -> Width works.
max-height:-moz-max-content; -> Height doesn't

Comment: `-moz-max-content` Can't **USED** with height